# Node "cannot find module" via ssh in Virtualbox

Tags: node.js, npm

I am running Debian stretch minimal in Virtualbox, headless, to test a node application.

I installed a dependency for my node application with `sudo npm install -g discord.js`. I install it globally because the directory my app is in (a shared directory to a Windows host) does not support symlinks.

Once I add `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to my `NODE_PATH` environment variable, I can run the app as expected directory from my Virtualbox window:

```
$ cd ~/my_app
$ node index.js
Connected
[...snip...]
```

But when I try to close the Virtualbox window and run the same app over SSH:

```
$ cd ~/my_app
$ node index.js
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
[...snip...]
```

My `NODE_PATH` environment variable is the same, and I can confirm the package is installed there:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules | grep "discord"
discord.js
```

I can even re-run `sudo npm install -g discord.js` from the SSH window and it does not give an error. How can this be?

Comment: Tip: do not globally install modules that you want to `require()`

Comment: "I install it globally because the directory my app is in (a shared directory to a Windows host) does not support symlinks."

Comment: (1) Did you log out of the virtualbox before you close the windows? (2) Are the shell the same when you login via windows and via ssh? (3) Is NODE_PATH set by hand manually each time you login or is it in some shell rc file?

Comment: (1) Doesn't have an effect either way, (2) Yes, (3) It's in an rc file, and I've verified the value is the same either way. Also I've noticed I get the error even in virtualbox when running as sudo

Answer (score 0):

declare NODE_PATH in ~/.profile or /etc/profile :

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules
```

.bachrc file is not sourced by default for ssh sessions